# Error during Eclipse plugin installation

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, eclipse-plugin

I'm new in Ubuntu. I have installed Eclipse (Mars2) on Ubuntu, it is working fine as a basic IDE.
But whenever I would like to add a plugin (help -> Install new software...) I got a question about if I trust the certificate from Eclipse Foundation. I select the cert and press Trust and I get the following error message after:

> An error occurred while installing the items
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.modeling, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.google.gson 2.2.4.v201311231704, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
>   Could not acquire the framework manipulator service.
>   Could not acquire the framework manipulator service.*

Can you tell me what I do wrong? Thx.

Comment: The error message is simiar to https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/783668/ What plugin do you want to install?

Comment: Hi,
It seems it solved. Once I started eclipse as root (sudo) and initiated the connection from there - after that I was able to initiate the connection with simple user. (Anyway I have tried to install BPMN2.)